# c# lambda expression to remove items from a list based on given conditions in a different list

Tags: c#, lambda

Say I have an `IList<int> ProductIds` that I am passing to a very slow web service.  That call would look like this:

```
var WebServiceResponse = client.SomeCall(ProductIds);
```

The list of ints will contain all product IDs for a given page.

I have another list, say `IList<Product>` where Product contains an `int ProductId` member property.  I want to call my web service, but before doing so I want to remove every item from ProductIds that has a Product in my other list with a matching ProductId.  Is there a one liner that can do this for me or do I have to run a loop?  I've tried all sorts of things but nothing compiles.  I'm still new to lambda expressions so hopefully this one is cake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var list = new List<Product>(); //or wherever you get it from
var otherIDs = list.Select(p => p.ProductId);
var WebServiceResponse = client.SomeCall(ProductIds.Where(i => !otherIDs.Contains(i));
```

If your web service takes a List or IList specifically, you'll need to add a ToList at the end:

```
var WebServiceResponse = client.SomeCall(ProductIds.Where(i => !otherIDs.Contains(i).ToList());
```

Comment: There is an Except method that can be used instead of your Where clause: ProductIds.Except(otherIDs)

Answer (score 0):

```
var excluded = ListA.Where(p=>!ListB.Contains(pb=>pb.Id == p.Id));
```

Could be a little bit different if ListB is only Ids, then it'll be just !ListB.Contains(p.Id)